# Access Variants for each Cart Item Shopify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify, liquid

First off, I always like to post runnable examples, but since this is a mix of js and server side rendered liquid on shopify I can't get a running example.

In shopify, you can access the `product` object like so `{{ product }}` from the product template.

The cart object has an `items` property which is an array of all the items in the cart. Each `item` object in the cart differs from the `product` object. The `product` object has a list of variants, the cart `item` object does not.

The purpose of this is to be able to edit the size of an item in the cart.

My question is, how would you be able to get all the linked variants? You would have to move up to the product and get a list of all the variants there, from the variant by it's `product_id`.

The reason this is tricky is because when you get the fetch response of the cart object, you get a `product_id` for each `item` in the cart. You can't get the product object though unless you are on the product page.

Just to help visualize the cart is something like this:

```js
{
  items: [
    {
      handle: 'product-handle',
      product_id: 123,
      variant_title: 'product variant'
    }
  ]
}
```

what needs to be accomplished is:

```js
{
  items: [
    {
      handle: 'product-handle',
      product_id: 123,
      /**
       * to get this you need first access to the product object from the product 
       * template. You could convert the product to json with a filter
       * e.g. const product = {{ product | json }} but you don't have the 
       * opportunity to be on the product template each time you edit a cart item
      */
      variants: [
        { color: 'white', size: 's' },
        { color: 'white', size: 'm' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting with this all day I finally got it. For anyone else that ever runs across this you need to do something like this.

From the cart template, `cart.liquid`

```js
const cart = (() => {
  const cart = {{ cart | json }}
  const items = []
  let variants

  {% for item in cart.items %}
    item = {{ item | json }}
    variants = []

    {% for variant in item.product.variants %}
      variant = {{ variant | json }}
      variants.push(variant)
    {% endfor %}

    item.variants = variants
    items.push(item)
  {% endfor %}
  cart.items = items

  return cart
})();
```

Now for each item property in the cart you have the variants for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a product ID or handle, you are free to make a call to Shopify to get more information about the product, such as all the variants assigned to it, and therefore, all the options. So to change to a different option, you would need to remove a variant ID from the cart, and add a different one, the one you want. You can use StorefrontAPI calls to get product information. That is typically how a merchant would do what you need done.

Comment: Right now I need to use the standard way, but I agree the storefront api would make this way easier. Is there a way I can get the product info somehow without the storefront api? The cart lets you send a fetch request, I have the whole product converted to js but ONLY on the product template. If I knew this when I first started I would have started clean with the storefront api and never bothered with liquid.

Comment: When you render a cart, you are also free to render whatever JS you need, representing the products in the cart. So you need make zero API calls if you knew you wanted to offer switching variants in the cart itself. Almost no one does that, but that does not mean you can't.